# async data not getting cleared

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have 3 async tasks currently running Login, Registration, and GetInstitutes. I made the Login class Function first and i know it worked fine, however adding the other 2 has caused it not to work. So When the app launches it does GetInstitutes and returns

```
{"institute":[{"id":"1","name":"plymouh university"},{"id":"2","name":"University Of Bradford"},{"id":"3","name":"University of West England"}],"success":1}
```

if i register it returns:

```
{"message":"Invalid email","success":0}
```

These run fine and get there JSON Objects fine, however when Login instead of getting the JSON object for login i get one of the previous Logins

```
class loginAttempt extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    JSONObject json = null;  //reseting the JSON Object to null to try and fix

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Show progress Dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String usernameSTR = username.getText().toString();
        String passwordSTR = password.getText().toString();


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usernameSTR));
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordSTR));



         Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());    //outputs null


         // getting JSON Object
         json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login,
                "POST", params1);                      //Performs Login request



        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());  //outputs original JSON from register or Get Institute not from the JSON above


       //manipulate results
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                //Dismiss Dialouge and show results
    }
 }
```

Comment: So what's the Problem descripe it in detail

Comment: The fact that even after nullifying the JSONObject, when i do 'json = jsonParser..' It displays the JSON Object from the previous example.

So say the Register Async task was called  then the Login task the JSONObject will show the Register JSONObject

Comment: may be you have declared json object as a global variable..mean at top level. try declaring it in doInBackGroundMethod

Comment: Can you please post the code of jsonParser.makeHttpRequest method?

Comment: Where do you initialize your json value? Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

Comment: @wqrahd tried, no luck even changed the name from the other JSON objects

Comment: @KLiFF Bottom of this page http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: check your makehttprequest method ..does url changes or not..mean does it calling everytime to the same url

Comment: @aegean The JSON value is initlized at the top of the class, it is then populated after and before the Log.d,  The first Log.d is null the second is the wrong JSONObject output

Comment: @wqrahd nope each uses a separate URL

Comment: If you are using the same instance of JSONParser and you get an exception in the second call you'll get the response from the last call. This is beacause the jObj var is not set at many times if there is an exception. Try using a new instance of JSONParser and also look at the cat log if there is any exceptions.

Comment: @KLiFF ahh yes thank you it is causing an exception i'll look into it now